What is the best way to express the frame bundle of a smooth manifold in terms of local isomorphisms with a trivial vector bundle?
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $FM$ denote its frame bundle. I'd like to think of $FM$ in terms of local isomorphisms $M\times V\to TM$, where $V$ is a real vector space such that $\dim V=\dim M$ and $TM$ is the tangent bundle of $M$. Also, I'd like to do so in such a way that the differentiable structure of $FM$, especially its exterior algebra, becomes the cleanest possible.
I tried using sheaves, but it seemed to me that the second requirement, related to the differentiable structure of $FM$, became a bit messy... Perhaps I'm missing some shortcut? Or is there a better strategy?

A local isomorphism as you have defined it is also called a local trivialization if $V = \mathbb{R}^n$. There is an equivalence between local trivializations and local frames. A local frame defines a local trivialization of the frame bundle. All of the smooth and bundle structures are preserved by this.
